# handlebars block helper is not registered

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, handlebars.net

My case is pretty similiar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46243554/how-to-output-block-with-handlebars-dot-net-conditional-helper?answertab=votes#tab-top)
Soo i have template like this

```
{{#each items}}
        {{#if_kpi category.group}}
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{indexOffset @index}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{categoryName}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{measurementDescription}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{target}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{formatPercentage weight}}
            </td>
        </tr>
        {{/if_kpi}}
        {{/each}}
```

and this is my block helper

```
 _handlebars.RegisterHelper("if_kpi", (writer, options, context, parameters) =>
            {
                string group = Convert.ToString(parameters[0]);

                if (group == Enum.GetName(typeof(KPICategoryGroupEnum), KPICategoryGroupEnum.KPI))
                {
                    options.Template(writer, (object)context);
                }
                else
                {
                    options.Inverse(writer, (object)context);
                }
            });
```

but when the data applied to my template, i always got error that says `Template references a helper that is not registered. Could not find helper '#if_kpi'`

is anything wrong with my block helper implementation

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint on `_handlebars.RegisterHelper` and verify it was executed?

Comment: well yeah i did, and it was executed & registered on BlockHelper (the other helper i used is registered on helper)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to register the helper using dependency injection, as your _handlebars is using the field formatted name, I think it doesn't work like that.

I think you should rather register the helper at startup.cs in configureServices, registerServices or anywhere else you you have access to the serviceCollection.

Such as:

```
      Handlebars.RegisterHelper("if_kpi", (writer, options, context, parameters) =>
        {
            string group = Convert.ToString(parameters[0]);

            if (group == Enum.GetName(typeof(KPICategoryGroupEnum), KPICategoryGroupEnum.KPI))
            {
                options.Template(writer, (object)context);
            }
            else
            {
                options.Inverse(writer, (object)context);
            }
        });
```

At least that worked for me.